# How do I create a dataframe from this list of strings?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a link to the csv file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4qlbah6yrw99fx/sample.txt?dl=0

Here is my code to read my csv file:

```
df = open("test.txt")
for l in f.readlines():
    data_extract = l.strip().split("\t")
    print(data_extract)
f.close()
```

Here is the output after reading the csv (pandas isn't working and tells me I need an integer):

['Fy', 'Fz', 'Mz', 'FLPt', 'IEPt', 'APPt', 'VP', 'Cal', 'VLAt', 'FLAt', 'IEAt', 'APAt', 'AbAt', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'VLSp', 'FLSp', 'IESp', 'APSp', 'VLWf', 'FLWf', 'IEWf', 'APWf', 'VLSm', 'FLSm', 'IESm', 'APSm', 'Fx 1', 'Fy 1', 'Fz 1', 'Mx 1', 'My 1', 'Mz 1', 'VPS1', 'SP11', 'SP12', 'Spc1', 'SP13', 'SP14', 'SP15', 'Fld1', 'Station']
['N', 'N', 'N-m', 'deg', 'deg', 'mm', 'N', 'N', 'Volts', 'Volts', 'Volts', 'Volts', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'N', 'deg', 'deg', 'mm', 'N', 'deg', 'deg', 'mm', 'N', 'deg', 'deg', 'mm', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N-m', 'N-m', 'N-m', 'mm', 'NA', 'N', 'Â°C', 'NA', 'NA', 'N-m', 'Volts', 'N']
['65.782', '656.083', '-1.985', ' 0.232', '-1.858', ' 1.685', '535.965', '-6.990', ' 2.227', ' 0.975', '-0.330', '-0.179', '4063.000', '23.000', '-1021.000', '1132.000', ' 0.000', ' 0.000', ' 0.000', ' 0.000', '595.840', ' 0.153', '-1.870', ' 1.758', '535.965', ' 0.232', '-1.858', ' 1.685', '-12.522', '64.476', '665.416', '12.400', ' 0.472', '-1.933', '13.181', '-0.240', '15.304', '-35.972', '-0.067', '-0.098', '-0.134', ' 2.847', ' 1.000']
['67.502', '703.480', '-2.060', ' 0.237', '-1.870', ' 1.682', '568.867', '-6.990', ' 2.310', ' 1.031', '-0.318', '-0.197', '4575.000', '30.000', '-1026.000', '1123.000', ' 0.000', ' 0.000', ' 0.000', ' 0.000', '670.888', ' 0.195', '-1.879', ' 1.744', '568.867', ' 0.237', '-1.870', ' 1.682', '-11.537', '66.749', '713.655', '13.856', ' 0.220', '-2.297', '13.184', '-0.135', '15.918', '-35.972', '-0.075', '-0.094', '-0.203', ' 2.847', ' 1.000']

Comment: Post sample of the contents of the CSV file.

Comment: Ayo! I posted the link to the csv file. Can you see it?

Comment: Okay I got your file. But would you mind making clear what are the columns to be created in dataframe. @Zane

Comment: @Zane would you mind including the column names for your dataframe in the question.

Comment: @JesonPun column 1 starting with Fy would be a good start for, because I could then do the rest

Comment: @Zane actually so Fy is a single column right

Comment: @Zane I inspected your file. The number of column names and the columns of your data was not matching

Comment: I can give you little guidance, first you have to read your file line by line then you should identify the line where your column names are stored and make a list of column names then find the line of data and make the list of data, make sure the data in converted to integer or float before storing. You can simply create dataframe with pandas